# Lubuntu 19.10 does not list geany / gnome-system-monitor / openssh-server packages using Muon

Tags: 19.10, muon-package-manager

Lubuntu 19.10 these packages where listed using Muon Package Manager:

- geany
- gnome-system-monitor
- openssh-server

On a fresh install of Lubuntu 19.10 having done:

```
sudo apt update
```

Muon does not show them.

Also:

```
$ apt-cache policy geany gnome-system-monitor openssh-server
geany:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.35-1
  Version table:
     1.35-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
gnome-system-monitor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.32.1-2
  Version table:
     3.32.1-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
openssh-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:8.0p1-6build1
  Version table:
     1:8.0p1-6build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 19.10, and those packages all show (*in Muon*), if you system is really *fresh*, I'd hope a `sudo apt update` would make them show for your system.

Comment: Please edit your original question to show the output of the following command line: `apt-cache policy geany gnome-system-monitor openssh-server`

Answer (score 0):

According to your edited question, `apt` sees candidates for these three program packages. Please try to install them with the following command lines

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install geany gnome-system-monitor openssh-server
```

and let us know the result.

I think it will work, so good luck :-)